# Spring @Autowire Multiple Objects

Tags: spring

I like code to be visually easy to read (subjective, I know).  Is there a a way in Spring to take the first form of code

```
@Autowired
private O1 o1
@Autowired
private O2 o2
@Autowired
private O3 o3
```

And do something like this:

```
@Autowired
private O1 o1
private O2 o2
private O3 o3
@Endautowire
```

I would find the code to be less cluttered.  I know I am being trivial and picky, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible only with a preprocessor for java sources. But totally not worth it in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

You can use constructor to inject all objects with one annotation:

```
private O1 o1;
private O2 o2;
private O3 o3;

@Autowired
public ClassA(O1 o1, O2 o2, O3 o3) {
    this.o1 = o1;
    this.o2 = o2;
    this.o3 = o3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There was times when people use to declare variable like,

```
int i1, i2, i3;
```

This is no longer considered as a best practice and **declaring each of them separately increases the readability**.

Coming to your question, as as mrembisz told it it has to happen, need to happen  in source files. Other wise the **java compiler should change to handle such a scenario**.

Coming to readability,  your solution will **only increase the code clutter and reduce the readability**, suppose I have 10 beans injected, every time I need to see above and below the code to know if it is auto-wired or not.

So, I doubt it worth spend time doing or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thought as the original poster, but after having read the answers, I completely agree with the consensus that it is better to individually annotate members.  I am upvoting the original question because it is a good question **in spite of its bad underlying assumption** and because it resulted in even better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not how you want with annotations.

You could make a uber type that takes these three, and add that type here.  Id only do that if you find yourself in this situation many time, or if it truly reflects a concept in your application.